# User signup testing with mocha and chai

Tags: node.js, express, tdd, mocha.js, chai

I am working on a user signup api by taking a test driven development approach.

I have a POST request to `/signup` where a user submits email and password. A successful response to `/signup` returns a 200 status code and then calls my internal POST login method at `/login`. A successful login returns a 302 status and redirects to the base url `/`.

How do I go about writing the chai test for expecting multiple status codes?

I am using **express** as my server, **supertest** as my http testing api, and **chai** as my testing library.

Comment: You use a mock to simulate the call to the /signup method where the call will return the 200 (or a 302) and then test that your code handles the result properly by changing the base url or that it calls your login method.

Comment: or simply view them as two (or three) tests